# Vue store race condition - second component is trying to display data before first component puts it to the store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have two components: `First.vue` and `Second.vue`

- `First.vue` computes some data on `created()` and puts it to store
- `Second.vue` displays the data from store via `computed` but gets: `Cannot read property "total" of undefined`

### First.vue

```
created() {
  fetchHddInfo().then(info => {
     this.$store.commit('updateMountedDrives', info)
  })}
}
```

### Second.vue

Data `{{freeSize}}` is displayed on the page, however I get `Cannot read property "total" of undefined` the first time computed tries to fetch the data from store (before data gets there from `First.vue`).

```
{{freeSize}}

...

computed: {
  freeSize () {
    return this.$store.state.AppData.mountedDrives.total.free
  }
}
```

### `AppData.js` store module

Example of what data `mountedDrives` stores:

`{"total": { "free": 201136054272, "size": 2114488328192 }}`

```
const state = {
  mountedDrives: []
}

const mutations = {
    updateMountedDrives (state, value) {
        state.mountedDrives = value
    }
}
```

Comment: mountedDrives is an array, if you want to display the total of items in the array, you should use the property length.

Comment: @Zysce `total` is the name of key of the array. Info stores the following: `{"total": { "free": 201136054272, "size": 2114488328192 }}}`

Comment: Can you add the declaration of your modules for Vuex instance?

Comment: @Zysce well, I'm importing modules as usual: `import modules from './modules'` and doing `export default new Vuex.Store({modules})`. second component gets the data from store after the first component puts it there, so the modules are definitely set up correctly. The issues is the error. I'm not sure how to prevent it getting the data before it's there

Comment: `this.$store.commit('updateMountedDrives', info)`, are you sure that info is not null or undefined? You should initialize the mountedDrives to `{}`. Since mountedDrives is initialized, the only thing which modify its value is in the hook of First.

Comment: @Zysce yep, if I do `console.log(value);` inside updateMountedDrives (state, value) { } I see the data in the console. But in the second component I'm tying to display that data on the page by getting computed value `{{freeSize}}`.